# How to debug shake rules execution?

Tags: haskell, shake-build-system

I love Shake as a build system, but one thing I find hard with Shake is to troubleshoot rules triggering issues. I often run into a situation where I *think* something should not be rebuilt yet it is rebuilt.

What are some guidelines to troubleshoot those kind of issues, beyond staring at the code and thinking hard?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a page entitled [Debugging](http://shakebuild.com/debugging) on the [Shake Website](http://shakebuild.com/). The [HTML profiling reports](http://shakebuild.com/profiling#html-profile) might also shed some light. The plan is to enhance the HTML profile reports to give a more question/answer style interface, tracked at [#446](https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues/446) and [#148](https://github.com/ndmitchell/shake/issues/148).

Comment: Thanks for the answer. I have seen the Debugging page and it does not really address my question: What I would like to have is something that explains to me the build plan, why each target has been rebuilt, which rules were triggered. I have used `Diagnostic` output but it is somewhat overwhelming even for a small project with a handful of rules.

Comment: I think the HTML profile reports should change to show you what you want to see, so perhaps open a ticket on the Shake issue tracker to record what you were looking for. If you can share the HTML profile I can shed some more light, but beware it likely contains detailed information about the files in your build.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, I will do that. Closing the question.